# VB access violation error

Tags: access-violation

I think I am having a problem with my sql database.  I have an application that is all of a sudden throwing an access violation error when ever the tableadapter is filled.

I believe that something may have happened to the database in general because if I pull up an earlier version of the program code, I get the same errors.

This is the line that it fails during

```
URTableAdapter.Fill(URDataSet.UR)
```

This is the Exception error text:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.ConstraintException' in System.Data.dll
>   System.Transactions Critical: 0 : xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" >Severity="Critical"
>   TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/200>4/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled >exceptionUR.vshost.exe>>
>   System.Data.ConstraintException, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, >Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Failed >to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, >unique, or foreign-key constraints.   at >System.Data.DataSet.EnableConstraints()
>     at System.Data.DataSet.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value)
>     at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader >dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, >DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, >IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 >startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
>     at UR.URDataSetTableAdapters.URTableAdapter.Fill(URDataTable dataTable) in >H:\Databases\UR\UREvolv\UR\URDataSet.Designer.vb:line 10650
>     at UR.DataEntry.LOCCB_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in >H:\Databases\UR\UREvolv\UR\DataEntry.vb:line 2103
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message&amp; m)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 >msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)>System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. >One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key >constraints.
>     at System.Data.DataSet.EnableConstraints()
>     at System.Data.DataSet.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value)
>     at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader >dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, >DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, >IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 >startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
>     at UR.URDataSetTableAdapters.URTableAdapter.Fill(URDataTable dataTable) in >H:\Databases\UR\UREvolv\UR\URDataSet.Designer.vb:line 10650
>     at UR.DataEntry.LOCCB_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in >H:\Databases\UR\UREvolv\UR\DataEntry.vb:line 2103
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message&amp; m)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 >msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>   The program '[13508] UR.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 >(0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Thank you for any help you may be able to give,

Steve

Comment: I just restored the DB to a different folder and called it UR2 from Friday earlyAM, I know it was working fine Friday afternoon. I restored my code from a backup of the same time period, changed the connection string from UR to UR2 in my application.

I am still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what happened to the original exe and DB, but I was able to restore an older copy of the program with a current backup of the DB and make the changes since previous version.

Thank you,

Steve